# How to implement a Buying NFT feature on solana program?

Tags: anchor-lang, anchor-spl

I am trying to implement a buying NFT feature in my solana program, but here i am struct on signature verification error.
Can anyone find out what i am missing here ?

[image]

```
pub fn buy_nft(
        ctx: Context<SellNft>,
       ) -> Result<()> {
        let sale = &mut ctx.accounts.sell_data;
        if !sale.is_open{
            return Err(ErrorCode::ItemNotOnSold.into());
        }
        if sale.is_sold{
            return Err(ErrorCode::ItemSold.into());
        }
        msg!("Initiating transfer of {} lamports...", sale.price);
        msg!("Purchaser (sending lamports): {}", &ctx.accounts.buyer_authority.key());
        msg!("Seller (receiving lamports): {}", &ctx.accounts.owner_authority.key());
        system_program::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                system_program::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.buyer_authority.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.owner_authority.to_account_info(),
                }
            ),
            sale.price
        )?;
        
        msg!("Lamports transferred successfully.");
        msg!("Transferring NFT...");
        msg!("Owner Token Address: {}", &ctx.accounts.owner_token_account.key());    
        msg!("Buyer Token Address: {}", &ctx.accounts.buyer_token_account.key());    
        token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                token::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.owner_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.buyer_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.owner_authority.to_account_info(),
                }
            ),
            1
        )?;
        msg!("NFT transferred successfully.");
        
        msg!("Sale completed successfully!");
    
        Ok(())
    }

    #[derive(Accounts)]
    pub struct SellNft<'info> {
        #[account(mut)]
        pub sell_data: Account<'info, Sale>,
       #[account(mut)]
        pub owner_token_account: Account<'info, token::TokenAccount>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub owner_authority: Signer<'info>,
        /// CHECK: We're about to create this with Anchor
        #[account(mut)]
        pub buyer_token_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
        #[account(mut)]`enter preformatted text here`
        pub buyer_authority: Signer<'info>,
        pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
        pub token_program: Program<'info, token::Token>,
    
    }
```

This is my frontend integration code:

```
   let tx = await program.methods
        .buyNft()
        .accounts({
          mint: TokenAddress,
          ownerTokenAccount: owner_associated_account,
          ownerAuthority: account.owner,
          buyerTokenAccount: receiver_associated_account,
          buyerAuthority: anchorwallet!.publicKey,
          sellData: nftSaleAccount,
          systemProgram:SystemProgram.programId
        })
        .rpc();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your instruction requires signing by an `owner_authority` and `buyer_authority`.

You can add addition signers by using `.signers([])`

```
   let tx = await program.methods
        .buyNft()
        .accounts({...})
        .signers([ownerAuthorityKeypair]) // 
        .rpc();
```

Additionally, it doesn't look like you're creating the `buyer_token_account` in the program. You can do so like this:

```
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = buyer_authority,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = buyer_authority
    )]
    pub buyer_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

You'll also need to update `Cargo.toml` to enable `init_if_needed`

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.28.0", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
```

Also just noticed you're using `Context<SellNft>` for your `buy_nft` instruction and the accounts in the `SellNft` struct doesn't include a `mint`. However, in your frontend integration code snippet, `mint` is one of the specified accounts.

Comment: Code worked when I passed the NFT owner keypair as a signer, but If I am the buyer then I am supposed to sign the transaction.
However it make sense also we cannot transfer someone else NFT to our account.
So how i can implement that feature where owner put the nft for sale and buyer connect their wallet and make the transaction to buy the NFT.

let tx = await program.methods
        .buyNft()
        .accounts({...})
        .signers([ownerAuthorityKeypair]) // 
        .rpc();